# Merging 2 JSONArrays having same keys in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have 2 JSONArrays that have same key as follows:

```json
{
    "data": {
        
            "Students": [
                {
                    "name" : "Alice",
                    "div" : "A",
                    "maths" : 56,
                    "science" : 89
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Bob",
                    "div" : "B",
                    "maths" : 87,
                    "science" : 34
                }
]}}
```

```json
{
    "data": {
        
            "Students": [
                {
                    "name" : "Charlie",
                    "div" : "C",
                    "maths" : 45,
                    "science" :67
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Doe",
                    "div" : "D",
                    "maths" : 56,
                    "science" : 78
                }
]}}
```

As in both JSON payloads I have the same JSONArray "Students", I want to combine both the JSONArrays into a single JSON Array as follows:

```json
{
    "data": {
        
            "Students": [
                {
                    "name" : "Alice",
                    "div" : "A",
                    "maths" : 56,
                    "science" : 89
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Bob",
                    "div" : "B",
                    "maths" : 87,
                    "science" : 34
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Charlie",
                    "div" : "C",
                    "maths" : 45,
                    "science" :67
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Doe",
                    "div" : "D",
                    "maths" : 56,
                    "science" : 78
                }
]}}
```

I want to achieve this using Java. Is there any way I can do it? Is there any Collection class that can serve this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create java model classes that corresponds to your json. This should include a list of Students.
2. Serialize both jsons into the java models.
3. Combine the 2 lists of students in one of the objects.
4. Deserialize the java object back to json string

Student:

```
public class Student {

private String name;
private String div;
private int maths;
private int science;
//getters setters constructors
}
```

Data:
public class Data {

```
private List<Student> students;
...
}
```

You also need some parent class to hold data, lets call it Parent:

```
public class Parent {

private Data data;
...
}
```

Now to run:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String json1 = "{\n" +
            "    \"data\": {\n" +
            "        \n" +
            "            \"students\": [\n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"name\" : \"Alice\",\n" +
            "                    \"div\" : \"A\",\n" +
            "                    \"maths\" : 56,\n" +
            "                    \"science\" : 89\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"name\" : \"Bob\",\n" +
            "                    \"div\" : \"B\",\n" +
            "                    \"maths\" : 87,\n" +
            "                    \"science\" : 34\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "]}}";

    String json2 = "{\n" +
            "    \"data\": {\n" +
            "        \n" +
            "            \"students\": [\n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"name\" : \"Charlie\",\n" +
            "                    \"div\" : \"C\",\n" +
            "                    \"maths\" : 45,\n" +
            "                    \"science\" :67\n" +
            "                },\n" +
            "                {\n" +
            "                    \"name\" : \"Doe\",\n" +
            "                    \"div\" : \"D\",\n" +
            "                    \"maths\" : 56,\n" +
            "                    \"science\" : 78\n" +
            "                }\n" +
            "]}}";


    Parent parent1 = mapper.readValue(json1, Parent.class);
    Parent parent2 = mapper.readValue(json2, Parent.class);

    parent1.getData().getStudents().addAll(parent2.getData().getStudents());

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(parent1));

}
```

you will get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "students": [
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "div": "A",
    "maths": 56,
    "science": 89
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "div": "B",
    "maths": 87,
    "science": 34
  },
  {
    "name": "Charlie",
    "div": "C",
    "maths": 45,
    "science": 67
  },
  {
    "name": "Doe",
    "div": "D",
    "maths": 56,
    "science": 78
  }
]
  }
}
```